# Bergbau, Bergwerk - woher stammt der Wortteil "Berg-"?

Tags: etymology

Unlängst mit einem Bekannten unterwegs, entspann sich eine Diskussion aus der sich die Frage ergab ob denn in den verschiedenen Bergbaubegriffen der Wortteil "Berg-" den entsprechenden mal hügeligen, mal felsigen Landschaftsmerkmalen oder eher dem Zeitwort "bergen" (bspw. "einen Schatz bergen") entspringt, beziehungsweise entsprang.

Die einschlägigen Quellen ließen sich nicht näher zu dem Thema aus, weshalb ich beschloß einfach einmal hier nachzufragen. Aus meiner persönlichen Sicht könnte es sich um Begriffe handeln welche aus bergigem Gebiet stammen und später auf andere Bereiche (Tagebau) übertragen wurden. Aber den Ursprung im Zeitwort "bergen" konnte ich nicht wirklich von der Hand weisen.

*Ganz wichtig:* bitte Quellen für die jeweilige behauptete/zitierte Ursprungsangabe hinzufügen.

Comment: Ich würde eher vermuten, dass die Herkunft tatsächlich von *bergen* der Rohstoffe kommt; vergleiche auch die Berge, kann aber dafür keine Quelle finden. Das Bisschen Bergehalde, was wir bei uns haben, ist aber auf jeden Fall zu klein, als dass es ein Bayer *Berg* nennen könnte. Auf jeden Fall verdammt interessante Frage.

Comment: Dazu wird man wohl auch den Zusammenhang von *Berg* und *bergen* klären müssen.

Comment: Es gibt ja auch "bergen" im Sinne von "enthalten" (vgl. auch "verbergen"); die Bodenschätze sind im Lager enthalten. Und der Bergbau fördert eben die Rohstoffe zutage, die das Lager birgt.

Comment: Man sollte beachten, dass historisch Berkwerke tatsächlich zuerst in den Bergen auftauchten, wo sich das Gesuchte durch natürliche Erdfaltungen an die Nähe der Oberfläche bewegte - Und die sind natürlich in den Bergen häufiger als in der Ebene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Beides **[der Berg](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB04143#XGB04143)** wie auch **[bergen](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GB04217#XGB04217)** haben eine gemeinsame Etymologie. So waren früher Berge nicht nur eine Erhöhung der Landschaft, sondern sie wurden vor allem als Schutzstätte empfunden, wie es sich auch in dem Wort **[Burg](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Burg)** widerspiegelt.

Ursprünglich kommt derselbe Wortstamm auch in der Bedeutung ["Ufer"](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009131_4_1_1485) vor, woraus sich letztlich das englische [*har**bor***](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=harbor&allowed_in_frame=0) (Altenglisch *herebeorg*) herleiten soll, und das nach Adelung ein Beleg für die Bedeutungsgemeinsamkeit von "Berg" und "bergen" ist (was auch die Grimms so teilen).

Eine Trennung des Berges *(Erhebung)* vom Bergen *(in Sicherheit bringen)* in den Komposita *Bergwerk, Bergbau, Bergmann* erscheint uns vielleicht erst heute als weniger klar.

So nannte man früher auch andere Werkstätten [Bergwerk](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GB04664#XGB04664). Und als [Bergmänner](http://lexika.digitale-sammlungen.de/adelung/lemma/bsb00009131_4_1_1597) wurden hauptsächlich Grubenarbeiter und nur in der Nebenbedeutung auch Bewohner der Berge benannt.

Nachdem Bergbau zwar überwiegend unter Tage, aber meist nicht in den Bergen betrieben wird, erscheint die Bedeutung des Bergens in den genannten Komposita sehr wahrscheinlich.

Neuere Quellen sagen aber einschänkend, dass möglicherweise die sowohl dem *Berg*, also auch dem Verb *bergen* zugrunde liegende Wurzel **[bherg-](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=bhergh-)** bereits im Indo-Europäischen zwei Bedeutungen hatte.

---

<sub>Quellen in den Links zu den einzelnen Wörtern</sub>

Comment: Bei DWDS wird keine gemeinsame Etymologie mehr erwähnt. "Berg" kommt von einem Ie. Wort, das "Erhöhung" bedeutet, "bergen" von einem das "bergen" heißt. Der Etymologieduden wiederum sieht "bergen" als höchstwahrscheinlich eine Ableitung von "Berg", wobei der kern von Berg die Idee einer Erhöhung ist, nicht die des Schutzes. Diese beiden neueren Quellen wollte ich nicht unerwähnt lassen.

Comment: @Emanuel sowohl bei "Berg" als auch bei "bergen" schreibt das DWDS, dass es auf die i.e. Wurzel  *bherg̑hos* bzw. *bhergh* zurückgehen soll... also schon irgendwie nahe beisammen...

Comment: Altnordisch/Isländisch herbergi als Ursprung von Englisch harbor, seeehr interessant. Vielen Dank auch für die Links. In diesem Lichte könnte ich mir gar vorstellen, daß die Bedeutung des "Bergens" (als Rettung von Personen) sich möglicherweise erst in Abwandlung aus dem Bergen von Bodenschätzen ergab.

Comment: Mir fällt zu dem Thema die Herberge ein. Bin mir nicht sicher wie sehr das von Berg und bergen abgeleitet wurde.

Comment: @Andie2302: richtig, das war immer meine Eselsbrücke für herbergi im Isländischen. Isländisch ist sehr bildhaft und hat man erst einmal die Eselsbrücke gefunden ist es relativ einfach, bspw. heißt das Echo "bergmál", also wortwörtlich "Bergsprache". (Stígvélaði kötturinn -> der gestiefelte Kater; wobei man aber auch die a-nach-ö Geschichte kennen muß)

Comment: "Und als Bergmänner wurden hauptsächlich Grubenarbeiter und nur in der Nebenbedeutung auch Bewohner der Berge benannt." - ich habe noch nie gehört, dass *Bergmann* heutzutage etwas anderes heißen soll als *Grubenarbeiter*. Ist der Satz so gemeint, wie er dasteht, mit der Implikation, dass heute im Gegensatz zu früher angeblich *Bergbewohner* die Hauptbedeutung von *Bergmann* sein soll?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: ähm - nö, "früher" und Präteritum stehen hier nicht ohne Grund.

Comment: @Takkat: Wenn deiner Aussage nach *früher* Grubenarbeiter als Bergmänner bezeichnet wurden, impliziert das für mich, dass es *heute* angeblich anders ist. Wenn das nicht so gemeint war, soll es mir recht sein, auch wenn mir die Formulierung irreführend scheint.

Answer (score 2):

Ich denke es kommt von "Berg". Eindeutige Belege habe ich nicht, wohl aber ein paar belegbare Argumente:

1) "Bergbau" ist sehr wahrscheinlich eine Parallele zu "Ackerbau", was früher auch mal "Ackerwerk" hieß. "Bergwerk" war die "Arbeit im Berg" genau wie "Ackerwerk" die Arbeit auf dem Acker war. Später wurde "Bergwerk" dann zum Ort und "Bergbau" zur Tätigkeit. Dazu stellt sich dann auch "Tagebau" was zwar nicht direkt ein Ort ist, aber doch beschreibt, wo man es macht, nicht was man macht (bergen).

2) Auf Schwedisch heißt "bergen" "att bärga" und "Berg" heißt "berg". Es gibt zwei Wörter für "Bergbau", nämlich "bergsbruk" und "gruvbrytning". In der ersten Version deutet die Schreibung auf eine Ableitung von "Berg" hin. Die zweite Version basiert auf dem Wort für "Grube", ist also ebenfalls eine Ableitung vom Ort.

3) Das Wort "Bergwerk" ist vermutlich schon sehr alt und hat sich in der Bedeutung kaum geändert. Käme es von "bergen", so gibt es keinen Grund, es nicht auch für andere Rohstoffe zu verwenden. Ich denke da zum Beispiel an Holz, aber man könnte ein auf "bergen" basierendes "Bergwerk" (im Sinne von "work") auch für zum Beispiel das Bergen von Verwundeten auf dem Schlachtfeld verwenden. Da es dafür aber keinerlei Belege gibt, wurde es wohl nie so verwendet.

Comment: Laut Wiktionary lassen sich sowohl schwedisch *berg* (über _*bergaz_) als auch schwedisch *bärga* (über _*berganą_) auf den gemeinsamen protoindogermanischen Stamm _*bʰergʰ_ zurückführen. Da der *Berg* im isländischen und färörischen *bjarg* heißt, genau wie *bergen* (*bjarga*) würde ich den Unterschied im Schwedischen auf eine spätere Lautverschiebung oder Schreibvariation dort zurückführen.

Comment: @Jan: nur wird im isländischen "fjall" heutzutage verwendet (siehe Eyjafjallajökull - also "Inselberggletscher"). Kann sein daß es mal verwendet wurde, aber aktuell scheinbar nicht mehr (kam mir in mehreren Jahren in Island leben nicht unter, "berg" hingegen schon, bspw. als "bergmál"; also Echo). Björg (auch Björgvín) als Vorname enthält aber noch eine gebeugte Form und soll laut (isl.) Freunden vom Wortsinnn her von "Berg" stammen. "að bjarga" findet man in der Tat, bspw. in "björgunarsveit". Siehe auch ordabok.net ;)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Gut, das sind Feinheiten, die mir als Außenstehendem, der die Wiktionaryseite von _*bergaz_ sich anschaut, nicht auffallen würden ^^'

Comment: *Björn* ist einem Witz zu laute der Name eines Frosches, bzw. das Geräusch, wenn derselbe überfahren wird. Offensichtlich verbirgt sich dahinter eine unverschobene Form des altererbten Namen Frankreichs, die ja als Frösche bekannt sind. Lautgesetzlich ist das schwierig, aber *Frosch* ist auch zweifelhaft vong Herkunft her. *Björg* könnte dazu zählen. Abgesehen davon ist niederdeutsch *Jörg* zu *Georg* im Christentumulus auffällig.